# Pupeteer - set the --remote-debug-port

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, puppeteer

I've got a piece of Pupeteer code that seems to run Chromium with `--remote-debugging-port=0`, which - as I understand - assigns *some* port available.

I want the port to always be the same, since I want to attach to Chromium with WebStom's debugger, and having it change every single launch forces me to look up the port and change the WebStorm launch configuration.

**How do I force Pupeteer to use a certain port for Chromium's debugging server?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can launch the chromium with `LaunchOptions` as following:

```
const option: LaunchOptions = {
        args: ['--remote-debugging-port=9222']
    };
const browser = await launch(option);
```

Since Launching a chromium browser with `--remote-debugging-port=0` assigns a random open port automatically. You can read [this thread](https://www.magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=15610) for more information.